# Using IsolatedStorage, Is it necessary to check if a directory exists before creating it?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm working on a Windows Phone 7 app, and I was wondering whether anyone had a definitive answer on whether or not I have to check if a directory exists before creating one, and what the advantages/disadvantages of doing/not doing so are. As far as I can tell, from stepping through my code, the following two blocks of code work in the same manner:

```
        using (IsolatedStorageFile appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {                
            //ensure directory exists
            String sDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath);
            if (!appStorage.DirectoryExists(sDirectory))
            {
                appStorage.CreateDirectory(sDirectory);
            }
        }
```

and

```
        using (IsolatedStorageFile appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {                
            //ensure directory exists
            String sDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath);
            appStorage.CreateDirectory(sDirectory);

        }
```

Is it safe to use the second block of code? It didn't seem to throw an exception if the directory already existed, and also seemed to leave the contents of the directory alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IsolatedStorageFile.CreateDirectory` will call `Directory.CreateDirectory` internally. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) of `Directory.CreateDirectory` states:

> If the directory already exists, this
>   method does nothing.

In other words, you don't need to check if that directory exists. The method already does that for you.

Comment: i swear i read the documentation before i asked this question, must have missed it - the joys of late night programming :)

Comment: No, you didn't mis it. It isn't in the `IsolatedStorageFile.CreateDirectory` documentation. It is in the `Directory.CreateDirectory` documentation. That `IsolatedStorageFile` calls `Directory` however, can be called an implementation detail and can change. But even when this changes internally, Microsoft has to make sure that `IsolatedStorageFile` does not throw an exception when the directory already exists, because this would be a behavioral (and thus breaking) change. Therefore it is a short come in the documentation that it doesn’t describe this. Perhaps you can report it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that internally `CreateDirectrory` is doing a check if the directory already exists or is swallowing an exception. Either way, there is probably a small performance benefit to be had from calling `DirectoryExists` explicitly before hand.

The way to test for sure would be to benchmark performance of the 2 methods with creating a large number of directories. (If you try this, be aware that you can't have more than 16k directories in a parent directory and you can't go more than 18 (I think) directories deep.)

It's better practice to be explicit about what you're doing. I would hope that any other developer who looked at the code would ask you you weren't testing for existence before creating a directory. Especially if this code was called many times. If you test and find no difference in performance, I'd recommend a comment in the code to state this.